# How can i import tamil letters to mysql db via excel upload?

Tags: php

How can i upload tamil letters from Excel sheet, I use `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">` and also trying to use `$ProductName = mb_convert_encoding($ProductName, "auto");` but the letter showing like `���� �����`.

I am using excel_reader2.php to import Excel sheet.

Please Help me solve this font issue

Comment: You can use unicode font in excel sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You should set utf-8 where you use connection:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "test");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

printf("Initial character set: %s\n", $mysqli->character_set_name());

/* change character set to utf8 */
if (!$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")) {
    printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
    exit();
} else {
    printf("Current character set: %s\n", $mysqli->character_set_name());
}

$mysqli->close();
?>
```

[Refrence link (php.net)](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php)

Comment: The database  is accept tamil font not getting from Excel